# Neo4j explicit/manual index queries, parameters in predicate and possible Cypher(SQL) injections

Tags: neo4j, lucene, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I'm going to use Neo4j explicit/manual index queries, something like that:

```
MATCH (d:Decision)-[:HAS_VALUE_ON]->(ch:Characteristic) 
WHERE ch.id = 2 
CALL apoc.index.in(ch,'HAS_VALUE_ON','property.1.4:5 AND property.1.3:"practical"') YIELD node AS decision 
MATCH (decision)-[ru:CREATED_BY]->(u:User) 
RETURN decision, u
```

In order to use it I need to create the index query predicate based on Lucene query language, for instance like the following in the example above:

```
'property.1.4:5 AND property.1.3:"practical"'
```

According to my business logic, the values inside of the predicate come from UI and potentially can be used for Cypher(SQL) injections.

Previously I used Cypher named parameters in order to avoid this issue but looks like it doesn't work inside of predicate string.

How to deal with it in case of explicit/manual index Lucene query predicate?

Comment: what about making the whole predicate a named parameter ? sth like `CALL apoc.index.in(ch, {relType}, {predicate})` ?

Comment: yes, good idea. Thanks, I'll try it